# How to calculate this covariant derivative?

Tags: tensors, differential-geometry

I try to calculate the covariant derivative:

$
\nabla_\beta \partial_\alpha~ \phi = \partial_\beta \partial_\alpha~ \phi
+ \Gamma^\sigma_{\beta\alpha} ~\partial_\sigma~ \phi
$

Where $\phi$ is a function of $(t)$. The problem is that the code that I uses gives only
$\nabla_0 \partial_0~ \phi$ correct which is $\nabla_0 \partial_0~ \phi = \ddot\phi + \dot{a} a^{-1} \dot{\phi}.$ While it should give the spatial components zero like $\nabla_3 \partial_3~ \phi$, but it gives
$\nabla_3 \partial_3~ \phi =\dot{a} a^{-1} \dot{\phi} $. Any help what is wrong with the following code?

```
clist := {t, x, y, z}


gd = a[t]^2  DiagonalMatrix[{-1, 1, 1, 1}];

gu = Inverse[gd] // Simplify;

 Γudd[aa_, bb_, cc_] := (1/2)*  Sum[gu[[aa,dd]]*(D[gd[[dd,cc]], clist[[bb]]] + D[gd[[dd, bb]], clist[[cc]]] - 
      D[gd[[bb, cc]], clist[[dd]]]), {dd, 1, Length[gd]}]

 Table[Γudd[a, b, c], {a, Length[gd]}, {b, 
  Length[gd]}, {c, Length[gd]}];



covDu[a_, b_] :=  D[D[A[t], clist[[a]]], clist[[b]]] +  
Sum[Γudd[a, b, c]* D[A[t], clist[[c]]], {c, 1,Length[gd]}]

Table[covDu[a, b], {a, Length[gd]}, {b, Length[gd]}];


covDu[1, 1]


covDu[3, 3]
```

Comment: Your expectation that $\nabla_0 \partial_0 \phi = \ddot{\phi} + \texttt{stuff}$ seems to be wrong. It should be just $\ddot{\phi}$. Yes? That's the major hint

Answer (score 1):

Your metric is conformally flat, a factor times the Minowski metric.

All Gamma are zero. Riemann and Weyl tensor are zero. Since the Weyl tensor is invariant under conformal transformations and is identical with the Riemann tensor in empty space, all these results are clear.  In your special case, only the time derivative reflects the rescaling of the time coordinate.

In order to check your code, use a   metric with different factors for time and space eg,
$$ds^2 =  dt^2 - a(t,(x^2+y ^2 +z^2))\ (dx^2+dy^2+dz^2) $$

Time rescaling alone is pointless, physically.

A piece of code from 1995

$$\left({{\Gamma^i}\, _l }\right)_k =
 \frac{1}{2}\ \sum_s \left(  {g^{-1}}_ {i s} \ \left(\ \
\partial_k g_{s l}+ \partial_s g_{ k l}- \partial_l g_{s k}\right)\right)$$

```
    Christoffel1[metric_, coo_] := 
  1/2 (Transpose[#, {2, 1, 3}] + 
       Transpose[#, {1, 2, 3}] - 
       Transpose[#, {3, 1, 2}] &)[D[metric, #] & /@ coo]
```

[image]

Comment: There's no actual need for all that. A simple inspection of the existing code is sufficient. Just check the entries in `Table[covDu[a, b], {a, Length[gd]}, {b, Length[gd]}]` with all the commands grabbed from the OP.

Comment: @bmf. So why the output of `Table[covDu[a, b], {a, Length[gd]}, {b, Length[gd]}]` is different from the output of `covDu[1,1]` or `covDu[3,3]` ?